# Does null Increase a strings length

Tags: java, string, null

I was doing a project and it asks that the length of a String has to be 8 and if it's less than 8 then fill it with a symbol, so Ii figure why not make it null. Just wondering if that would work for increasing the length of the String.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "why not make it null"? And which symbol are you meant to "fill" it with? Your question is unclear.

Comment: You mean adding a white space ? 

like **" "** ??

Comment: if they do not have the same length, the shorter sequence is padded at the end with enough blanks(a symbol that is just a filler) if that clears anything up

Comment: Add an example , Add an example for your idea also , to clarify your question

Comment: Do you know what `null` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You shouldn't pad a string with the [null character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), or with the `null` value. You definitely want to pad it with the blank string `" "`:

```
String string = "abc"; // too short!
while (string.length < 5) {
    string = string + " ";
}
```

Comment: That is what i'm aiming for i think, thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget that you can accept answers that help you out - this encourages people to answer your future questions. Once you get 15 points, you can upvote helpful answers as well, like Eran's.

Answer (score 1):

`null` is not a symbol, so no, it wouldn't work. If you append a null to a String it would append the String "null", which is probably not what you want. You can fill it with empty space characters.